# How to align spaces in PowerShell code output?

Tags: powershell

This is my PowerShell code:

```
$Phones = @('iPhone 12', 'Samsung S5', 'Nokia 7')
$Manufs = @('US', 'South Korea', 'Finlandia')
$n = 0
$Phones | foreach {
    "$($_) : $($Manufs[$n])"
    $n++
}
```

Output:

```shell
iPhone 12: US
Samsung S5: South Korea
Nokia 7: Finlandia
```

How to align space/ tab before `:` so it becomes:

```shell
iPhone 12  : US
Samsung S5 : South Korea
Nokia 7    : Finlandia
```

Comment: What about the [`PadRight` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-8.0)? Something like this: `$_.PadRight(12)`.

Comment: Since you know the keys (phones) beforehand, just find the longest one and use it in PadRight as @giacomo1968 suggested.

Comment: As @Giacomo1968 stated, it would look like this implemented: `$Phones | foreach {
    "$($_.PadRight(12)) : $($Manufs[$n])"
    $n++
}`

Comment: Thanks much for all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [get the length of the longest string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23628385/1115360) then you can use string interpolation with formatting ([format operator `-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#format-operator--f)), perhaps something like this:

```
$Phones = @('iPhone 12', 'Samsung S5', 'Nokia 7', 'Samsung Galaxy S II Epic 4G Touch')
$Manufs = @('US', 'South Korea', 'Finlandia', 'South Korea')
$maxLen = ($Phones | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
$formatString = "{0, -$maxLen} : {1}"
$n = 0
$Phones | foreach {
    $formatString -f $_, $Manufs[$n]
    $n++
}
```

To get:

```
iPhone 12                         : US
Samsung S5                        : South Korea
Nokia 7                           : Finlandia
Samsung Galaxy S II Epic 4G Touch : South Korea
```

If you wanted the first item right-aligned in its "column", you could use:

```
$formatString = "{0, $maxLen} : {1}"
```

(notice there is no `-` in that one) to get:

```
                        iPhone 12 : US
                       Samsung S5 : South Korea
                          Nokia 7 : Finlandia
Samsung Galaxy S II Epic 4G Touch : South Korea
```

Comment: Thanx for your full code